# Projecting 3D points in image plane

Tags: matlab, image-processing, 3d, mapping

I'm trying to project 3D point cloud onto image plane following the provided formulas from - [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/188577/tof-and-rgb-stereo-vision-system/?comment=189242#post-id-189242). 
The code I have is :

```
Td=[0.994700168903275 0.0521802707917803 0.0885934158044077 -1.09405637454607/1000; -0.0536097887263755 0.998466155670681 0.0138320834629078 24.2728498290288/1000; -0.0877357654352521 -0.0185082500606608 0.995971826982662 9.35239973330908/1000; 0 0 0 1];
xd=xyz(:,1); 
yd=xyz(:,2);
zd=xyz(:,3);
xyz_c=zeros(76800,4);
for i=1:76800
   b=[xd(i); yd(i); zd(i); 1];
   xyz_c(i,:)=mtimes(Td,b);
end
uc=(xyz_c(:,1)./xyz_c(:,3))*250.406303917333+162.663763325924;
vc=(xyz_c(:,2)./xyz_c(:,3))*249.362838052888+119.937781665327;
figure(1)
imshow(scene2);hold on; plot(uc,vc);hold off;
```

The translation vector is devided by 1000 because the value is in mm but I need it in m. `scene2` is the corresponding scene I want to match 3D points to. Somehow I get that the projected points are too low, in other words, the vc value is too big. When I plot `uc` and `vc` on image I get this:

[image: projection image]

It is hard to see but the top of the marker from 3D points is somewhere about where the cap of the marker starts, the points should be arround 60 pixels higher. When I do the following `imshow(scene2);hold on; plot(uc,vc-60);hold off;` the result is much better:

[image: result]

I obtain a point cloud with XYZ coordinates, so the xyz variable is basically information straight from exported point cloud. Hope I explained my problem good enough.

The question is, is there anything wrong with code or am I missing something?

Image: [image] 
`[uc,vc]` plot: [image]
Point cloud:[image]
Depth image:[image]

Comment: you should embed the images, that would make it easier to read

Comment: @Tobi I would but I don't have enough reputation in here. I recently joined

Comment: can you add the images without points overlayed (I am having a lot of trouble figuring out what is going on in the pictures)

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear I added the original image, the resulting [uc,vc] plot and the original point cloud (the black circle is where the pink marker is, its just hard to see it)

Comment: And maybe someone of you know the code of assigning pixel color value to the point cloud points, so in the result I get  colored point cloud

Comment: sry last request, do you know the xyz positions of your cameras or distance between?  *i can prolly get it with some trig from the images but just wondering*

Comment: ... any chance u have the point cloud as a 2d image ie depth image?

Comment: @SneakyPolarBear well the distance between the cameras is expressed in translation vector which is in Td matrix. I hope that answers your question. And yes I have a depth map of the scene as well. I'll add it to the post shortly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your cTd transformation matrix is corret, the only thing comes to my mind is that the row and column are swapped in Matlab. So, change the equations to:

```
uc=(xyz_c(:,1)./xyz_c(:,3))*250.406303917333+119.937781665327;
vc=(xyz_c(:,2)./xyz_c(:,3))*249.362838052888+162.663763325924;
```

Give it a try, but I am not sure, though. As you said, the pixel is off only in vc. However, it should be around 40 pixels off in both directions.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Another reason I thought that may cause this is that translation vector in the R|t matrix is in meters but the principial point and focal length is in pixels. Could that be the problem?

Comment: When I change the principial points it gets even worse. cTd transformation matrix I obtained using Matlab stereo calibration tool. Camera1 was the RGB camera, and I just copied the R matrix and t vector from the calibration output. The thing is I used amplitude images from ToF sensor to do the stereo calibration, maybe there is something wrong with that

Comment: @Kuchx, let me try the same with my Kinect and stereo calibration toolbox and then I will get back to you.

Comment: Very well, I'll be waiting for your results!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, user Amro helped me and pointed out the problem. If you remember RGB was camera1 and ToF sensor was camera2 when I did the stereo calibration. The problem was, when I was trying to tranform the 3D point (from ToF) to image frame `x1 = R*x2 + t=Td*x2` the idea I had was just to input the 3D coordinate values in `x2` and then I'll get the corresponig coordinates in image frame but actually I had to `x1=inv(Td)*x2` and now the scenes overlay as they should be based on the theory that was supported - [here](http://answers.opencv.org/question/188577/tof-and-rgb-stereo-vision-system/). Thanks everyone for the answers, much appreciated!

Regards 
Kuchx